# GetItems (CamlQuery) does not return all columns in the SharePoint list/ document library with REST API POST Request

Tags: rest, csom, jsom, office-365-developer

Required to get all column data with CAML query with GetItems REST API query since with the requirement of getting managed metadata term values. But **its not returning all** columns and values.

***Query as below:***

```
 var camlQuery = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\"/><Value Type=\"Counter\">" + itemId + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"; 

 method: 'POST', 
                    url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(\'" + listDisplayName + "\')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={\'ViewXml\':\'" + camlQuery + "\'}", 
                    headers: { 
                        'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 
                        'X-RequestDigest': formDigestValue 
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After few workarounds, found that issue was with the **throttling**. After increasing limits it will work fine, with no issues same as *GetByTitle(‘ListName')/items* SharePoint REST endpoint.

*Steps =>*
**Central Admin> Application Management> Manage Web Applications> Resource Throtling General Settings>** [image]

Comment: This is no solution, this is just postponing the problem for later, or killing your SQL server behind the sharepoint :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define all fields need to fetch in <ViewFields> tag.

```
  var camlQuery = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\"/><Value Type=\"Counter\">" + itemId + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='LinkTitleNoMenu'/><FieldRef Name='BatchSize'/></ViewFields></View>";
```

Comment: Requirement is to get all columns with data, So increasing throttling limit is the answer as I mentioned.